# My HTTP interceptor is not working, how could I fix it?

Tags: angular

My server is sending an error for expired token and I want catch it for redirect to login.
This is the code, where I make an mistake?

```
  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(req).pipe(
      map((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
        if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
           console.log('i'm here!');
        }
        return event;
      }),
      catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
// NEVER CACHT THE ERROR 
          localStorage.clear();
          sessionStorage.clear();
          this.nav.goToLogin('');
          return throwError(error);
      }));
  }
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting in the catchError block?

Comment: Ey Nicholas K, is SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR or SC_UNAUTHORIZED

Comment: I meant what doesn't work with your current attempt of redirection? Please have a look around and read through the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help). In particular [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Always quote the exact error, rather than just saying you get an error. We also need a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I'm not getting an error.. the server is sending the error but this part is working like there isn't an error
                                                                                                                
catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
// NEVER CATCH THE ERROR 
          localStorage.clear();
          sessionStorage.clear();
          this.nav.goToLogin('');
          return throwError(error);
      }));
  }

Answer (score 0):

you need to provide your interceptor in app module

```
 providers: [{
    provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
    useClass: MyInterceptor,
    multi: true
  }
```

Comment: I did @AlleXyS ... isn't the problem